# Navigation Editor tool in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ IDEA has implemented [Navigation editor tool](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor) from Android Studio and are there plans to do this?

This tool is so far the closest thing to XCode Storyboard given to the Android developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ Community Edition has the same Android Plugin that powers the Android-specific functionality in Android Studio, so yes, it will be there. Android Studio updates much more frequently than IntelliJ does for most of its release cycle, so if you want to pick up the latest functionality and bug fixes, Android Studio will be the way to go.

Note that the Navigation Editor will work only for Android projects; it won't be useful for non-Android projects you're developing in IntelliJ.